# Axon Distributed Command Bus on Docker Swarm

Tags: distributed, docker-swarm, axon

We use Axon and I am trying to make a distributed command bus for one of our services Deployed on Docker Swarm.

Anyone already have experiance/tips for setting this up?
We are using:

- Axon
- Docker Swarm
- Spring-Boot

And I want to use **JGroups** icw **DNSPING** for the distributed setup.

Regards,
Johan.

Comment: please post the code you already tried

Comment: which distributed command bus implementation do you use? JGroups, for example, will require some configuration to bind to the correct NIC. With Spring Cloud Discovery, you will need to make sure nodes publish their public (i.e. container) IP and port.